# Regular expression substitutions

Tags: c#

I am developing an expression evaluator, and I have the following code to check that I do not know the following combination of characters

for example:

*-- a multiplication followed by two subtraction signs

*/ a multiplication followed by a division

*+ a multiplication followed by a sum

this is the code that works correctly

```
private static Boolean EvaluaExprMat (String expr)
{
    for (int pos = 0; pos <expr.Length - 1; pos ++)
    {
      char car1 = expr [pos];
      char car2 = expr [pos + 1];

      if (car1 == '+' || car1 == '-' || car1 == '*' || car1 == '/' || car1 == '^')
        if (car2 == '+' || car2 == '*' || car2 == '/' || car2 == '^')
          return true;
    }

    for (int pos = 0; pos <expr.Length - 2; pos ++)
    {
      char car1 = expr [pos];
      char car2 = expr [pos + 1];
      char car3 = expr [pos + 2];


      if (car1 == '+' || car1 == '-' || car1 == '*' || car1 == '/' || car1 == '^')
        if (car2 == '+' || car2 == '-' || car2 == '*' || car2 == '/' || car2 == '^')
          if (car3 == '+' || car3 == '-' || car3 == '*' || car3 == '/' || car3 == '^')
            return true;
    }
```

How could I run these evaluations using regular expressions? can someone help me a little with this issue, I want to reduce the code using that kind of tool.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Use following

```
string pattern = @"(\*--)|(\*/)|(\*+)";
```

Comment: nice sweety, but how can I make the pattern identify me when, for example, the text string contains ++ or -- or +--  .. I am trying to evaluate a mathematical operation with regular expressions. Thanks

Comment: i try string InvalidPattern = @"(\++)|(\+-)|(\+/)|(\+*)|(\--)|(\-+)|(\-/)|(\-*)|(\//)|(\/+)|(\/-)|(\/*)|(\**)|(\*+)|(\*-)|(\*/)";
            if (Regex.IsMatch(Expresion, InvalidPattern))
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;    but always return false when evaluate (16+4)/5-(5+8)*(1-2)

Comment: string pattern = @"(\*--)|(\*/)|(\*+)|(++)|(--)|(+--)";